# None gradient using custom loss function that uses MSSIM

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am a novice with TensorFlow. I am trying to create a custom loss function that uses MSSIM. I am trying to calculate the MSSIM of a ground truth with the gradcam++ sailancy map of the input image.

Below are some code snippits.

Map calculation:

```
def calc_maps(model, HE_images, HE_labels):
HE_labels = list(tf.argmax(HE_labels, axis=1))
replace2linear = ReplaceToLinear()
score = CategoricalScore(HE_labels)
gradcam = GradcamPlusPlus(model, model_modifier=replace2linear, clone=True)
cam = tf.convert_to_tensor(gradcam(score,HE_images,penultimate_layer=-1))
return cam
```

A trail I did:

```
E, IHC = train_data_loader[0]
LABELS = tf.convert_to_tensor(HE[-1])
HE = tf.convert_to_tensor(HE[:-1][0])
IHC = tf.convert_to_tensor(IHC[:-1][0])

MAPS = 1 - calc_maps(model, HE, LABELS)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
predect = model(HE) #forward

im1 =tf.image.convert_image_dtype(IHC, tf.float32)
im2 =tf.image.convert_image_dtype(MAPS, tf.float32)

im2 = tf.expand_dims(im2, axis=-1)

ssim = tf.image.ssim_multiscale(im1, im2, 1.0)
gradients = tape.gradient(ssim, model.trainable_variables)

print(gradients)
```

Gradient is all NONE

Comment: Look at the [docs of GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape), the `tape.gradient()` call is done with `y` and `x` in the example. You don't compute the gradients with `model.trainable_variables`, nor with `ssim` in this form. You have to use the model prediction somehow, otherwise there are no gradients.